# datatables php json mikrotik

Tags: php, array, json, datatables

alguien quien me diera luces, quiero hacer un CRUD datatable con datos que tomo de un servidor mikrotik que obtengo mediante php y paso a json.

Quiero alistar los array para utilizar en datatables con json y funciones.

```
<?php
require('routeros_api.class.php');
require('ip.php');
$API = new RouterosAPI();
$data = new StdClass();
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
if ($API->connect($ip,$user,$pw)) {
       $API->write('/queue/simple/getall');

       $READ = $API->read(false);
       $ARRAY = $API->parseResponse($READ);

       $API->disconnect();

       $count = count($ARRAY);
       $data->c = $count;
       $data->estado = 1;
       //var_dump($ARRAY);
       if($count>0){
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $ip = explode('/', $ARRAY[$i]['target']);
            $speed = explode('/', $ARRAY[$i]['max-limit']);
            $data->id[] = $ARRAY[$i]['.id'];
            $data->ip[] = $ip[0];
            $data->name[] = $ARRAY[$i]['name'];
            $data->up[] = $speed[0]/1000000;
            $data->down[] = $speed[1]/1000000;
                $data->Comentario[] = $ARRAY[$i]['comment'];
        }
       }


        } else {
            $data->estado = 0;
        }
            echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

Es un datatable row details la idea es montar las funciones para poder editar, crear y eliminar los registros, tengo datatables e idea pero con ajax en append.

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
 function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Full name:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
  }

   $(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
 
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

} );

quien me pudiera ayudar estoy atento se que podria de igual apoyar en algo no mucho pero algun aporte por la ayuda, no es para vender es para mi uso en mis equipos administracion

Comment: y cual es el error???

Comment: no es tanto error, es que no he podido que tome los datos de mi php, en datatables.  `"columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "ip" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "up" }  `  quiero alistar el php para que el datatables tome los array eso no lo se de igual poner las funciones o switch

Comment: si la tabla no obtiene los datos debe estar teniendo un error de sintaxis ... el cual no podemos adivinar...